# Choose to display Quick Launch bar via DLL call

Tags: windows, shell, dll

I want to enable users to view the windows Quick Launch bar via DLL call (I checked the registry modification option but it's the route around).

I know the functionality is stored in `shell32.dll` and it the DLL can be accessed by `rundll32.exe`.

> rundll32.exe shell32.dll

**My question is:**

Can anyone point me to a through reference of the shell32.dll entry points and arguments, or knows of a program that extracts it from the DLL itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raymond Chen from the Windows shell team discusses this in a [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/02/9388941.aspx).

In short there is no documented, supported way to do this on XP. You'll need to continue using the hack you've found. In Vista you can use ITrayDeskBand. Windows 7 task bar is, of course, different again.

Raymond also points out that programs should not be changing the user's choice of visibility for the Quick Launch bar.

> That's not something a program should be doing. Whether
>   the Quick Launch bar is shown or hidden is an end user
>   setting, and programs should not be overriding the user's
>   preferences. Explorer consciously does not expose an
>   interface for showing and hiding taskbar bands because it
>   would just be a target for abuse. Much like the program that wants to uninstall other programs, the taskbar would become a battleground among programs that each wanted
>   to force themselves on and force their opponents off. The user is the arbiter of what goes into the Taskbar.

Comment: It's not an application modifying the user interface, it is for administrative purpose, since Microsoft didn't bother to provide nor info nor tools to achieve this.

Comment: @Dean Fair enough, but I was just pointing out the MS justification for the state of affairs. Sorry my answer isn't helpful.

Comment: The reason not to allow this is very rational, Imagine app vendors playing with your setting like they shove their toolbars into browsers... I looked high and low and found no resources on this, even opened the DLL. eventually I choose the more practical way of modifying the registry, works well. Thanks.